# Discord.js bot unable to leave voice channel

Tags: discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make a discord bot that plays an audio file. Right now, it joins the voice channel and plays the audio file, but refuses to leave afterwards. My code is below. Can anyone suggest some fixes so that my bot will leave the voice channel?

```
  var voiceChannel = client.channels.cache.get("693280991812517952");
  voiceChannel.join().then(connection =>{
    const dispatcher = connection.play('./00.mp3');
    dispatcher.on('end', () => voiceChannel.leave());
  }).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `finish` event instead of the `end` event.

So your solution is:
`dispatcher.on('finish', () => voiceChannel.leave());`

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it! In general, do you know where I can find these events? The discord.js api doesn't include the finish event for a StreamDispatcher.

Comment: Yeah, discord.js does not document things inherited from the standard Node.js library.

It is inherited from Node.js' WriteableStream: https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_finish